# Design Advise: Sending signals to daemons through HTTP

Tags: perl, security, networking, cgi

I'm using Apache on Ubuntu.  I have a Perl script which basically read the files names of a directory, then rewrites a text file,  then sends a signal to a daemon.  How can this be done, as secure as possible through a web-page?

Actually I can run a simplified cgi in the code below, but not if I remove the comments. I'm looking for advise considering any of:

- Using HTTP Requests?
- How about Apache file permissions on the directory shown in code?
- Is htaccess enough to enable user/pass access to the cgi?
- Should I use a database instead of writing to a file and run a cron querying the db with permission granted to write and send the signal?
- Granting as less permissions as possible to the webserver.
- Should I set a VPN?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use CGI;
#@fileList = </home/user/*>; #read a directory listing
my $query = CGI->new();

print $query->header( "text/html" ),
$query->p( "FirstFileNameInArray" ),
#$query->p( $fileList[0] ), #output the first file in directory
$query->end_html;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, could you try to explain what you're trying to achieve? (I mean, what has 'read the file names of a driectory, then rewrites a text file, then sends a signal to a daemon' got to do with CGI?)

Comment: I'm trying to run a script I have, securely through a web interface

Comment: @row the code is like I'm trying to output to HTML a directory listing

Comment: You are talking about security. What is the security model? Is anyone supposed to run this program over the Web? Please [amend your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4690084/edit).

Comment: @daxim Thanks I made the edits, feel free to make improvements to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the error you're getting from the commented lines is a permission denied when trying to read the `/home/user` directory.  The way to fix this is (surprise, surprise) to give the apache user[1] to read that directory.  There are three primary approaches to doing this:

1. In most environments, there's
   really no good reason to hide all
   filenames within a user's home
   directory, so you could make the
   directory world-readable with `chmod
   a+r /home/user`.  Unless you have a
   specific reason to prevent the
   general public from knowing the
   names of the files in the user's
   home directory, I'd tend to
   recommend this approach.
2. If you want to be a bit more
   restrictive about it, you could
   change `/home/user` to be owned by a
   group which the apache user belongs
   to (or add the apache user to the
   group that currently owns
   `/home/user`) and then set
   `/home/user` to be group-readable. 
   This will make it accessible to all
   members of that group, but not the
   general public.
3. If you need to have standard
   filesystem permissions applied to
   web access, you can look at
   configuring `suexec` so that
   individual requests can take on
   permissions of users other than the
   apache user.  This is normally the
   user who owns the code which is
   being run to handle the request
   (e.g., in this case, the user who
   owns your directory-listing script),
   but, if you're using htaccess-based
   authentication, it may be possible
   to configure `suexec` to decide
   which user's permissions to take on
   based on what user you log in as. 
   (I avoid `suexec` myself, so I'm not
   100% certain if this can be done and
   have no idea how to go about it if
   it can.)

[1] ...by which I mean the user that apache is running as; depending on your system config, this user may be named "apache", "httpd", "nobody", "www-data", or something else entirely.

Comment: Shreohman Thank you very much, btw I also need write permissions and send a signal to a daemon. That's my main concern.

Comment: Ah, right, forgot about those parts... The rewrite can also be arranged through normal unix permission grants, but you can only send signals to processes you own, so, unless the daemon can be run by the apache user from the start, then I guess you will need to use `suexec` after all.